# Content Area IDs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template

I'm developing a custom template that I've imported into Content canvas and then applied to an email using content builder , however I can't seem to find anything on ET to tell me what the ID of a content area i've created is.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#ContentArea

eg I would like to know what the id is for the content area in this snippet of code.

```
  <tr>
     <td style="text-align: center;padding-top: 24px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 15px;line-height: 21px;letter-spacing: 1px;" class="sectionMainContent"><a href="%%=RedirectTo(@leadctalink)=%%" class="ctatext" target="_blank" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;text-decoration: none;color: #000000;font-weight: bold;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;letter-spacing: 1.5px;">

          <custom type="content" name="leadcta">
                      </a></td>
                  </tr>
```

Comment: I think I figured out my own question. An ID exists for Content Areas that have been created outside of a template , what I have is just the content slot which a Content Area can be inserted into..

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, in addition I was told by our account rep that we cannot use any of the ampscript content area functions within Content Canvas, I have not tested this because I chose not to have it turned on due to that. If you have trouble pulling in content based on the ID that may be why.

Marsha